# this.add.image is not a function /w Phaser 3 - 3.16

Tags: javascript, function, phaser-framework

I am trying to add a button to a title screen and I am getting this.add.image is not a function.

I have changed image to someother verbiage and nothing else happens. I am using Zenva's academy and following along with the tutorials and have ran into this issue.

Here is my code

```
class UiButton extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container {
    constructor(scene, x, y, key, hoverKey, text, targetCallback){
        super(scene, x, y);
        this.scene = scene; // the scene this container will be added to
        this.x = x; // x pos
        this.y = y; // y pos
        this.key = key; // BG image of button
        this.hoverKey = hoverKey; // image displays when hovered
        this.text = text; // text displayed on button
        this.targetCallback = targetCallback; // the callback function that will be called when clicked
    
        this.createButton(); // Creates UI Button
        this.scene.add.existing(this); // adds this container to our Phaser Scene
    }

    createButton() {
        //create Play Game Button
        this.button = this.add.image(0, 0, "button1");
        
        //make button interactive
        this.button.setInteractive();

        //scale the button
        this.button.setScale(1.4);


        //create button text
        this.buttonText = this.add.text(0, 0, this.text, {fontSize: "26px", fill: "#fff"});
        //center text in ui button
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(this.buttonText, this.button);

        //add the two game objects to container
        this.add(this.button);
        this.add(this.buttonText);

        //Listen for events
        this.button.on("pointerdown", () => {
            this.targetCallback();
        });

        this.button.on("pointerover", () => {
            this.button.setTexture(this.hoverKey);
        });
        
        this.button.on("pointerout", () => {
            this.button.setTexture(this.key);
        });
        

    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The container object has an `add(child)` method. However it takes an existing game object. I think you are trying to build the image and would need to use the scene (the factory from the scene) to do that. Therefore, you should try:

```
this.button = this.scene.add.image(0, 0, "button1");
```

The same would be for the text:

```
this.buttonText = this.scene.add.text(0, 0, this.text, {fontSize: "26px", fill: "#fff"});
```